# TFS: move code between two files with history

Tags: tfs

I'm going to move a large piece of code from one file to another, both files have long history in TFS and I'd like to do something to keep the history. E.g. when someone displays annotation of the file, I want the changes to be tracked to the author, not everything as made by me.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful idea, but I the only version control system that is trying to do this is [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/), but I don't think they are already able to do this.